# Problem module ''x'' has no attribue ''y'' in my first CRUD with Python

Tags: python, module, attributes, crud, streamlit

main.py :

```
import streamlit as st;
import Controllers.ClienteController as ClienteController
import models.Cliente as cliente





with st.form(key="include_client"):
    input_name = st.text_input(label="Name")
    input_age = st.number_input(label="Age", format= "%d", step=1)
    input_occupation = st.selectbox(label="Select your occupation", options= ["Developer", "Engineer", "Doctor"])
    input_button_submit = st.form_submit_button(label="Submit")

if input_button_submit:
    cliente.name = input_name 
    cliente.age = input_age
    cliente.occupation = input_occupation 
    ClienteController.Incluir(cliente)
```

Folder models: (models>cliente.py)
cliente.py :

```
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, name, age, occupation):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age 
        self.occupation = occupation
```

folder services : (services>database.py)
database.py :

```
import pyodbc 


server = 'localhost' 
database = 'crud' 
username = '' 
password = '' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

folder Controllers : (Controllers>ClienteController.py)
ClienteController.py:

```
import services.database as db;


def Incluir(cliente):
    count = db.cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO crud (name, age, occupation) 
    VALUES (?,?,?)""",
    cliente.name, cliente.age, cliente.occupation).rowcount
    db.cnxn.commit()
```

When i run my streamlit and my main.py im getting this error :

```
 File "C:\Users\h1ckzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 556, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\h1ckzz\Desktop\CRUD\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    ClienteController.Incluir(cliente)
AttributeError: module 'Controllers.ClienteController' has no attribute 'Incluir'
```

So when i press the button submit in my forms, this error shows up. Any solutions ?

Comment: Its behaving as though the .py file hasn't been saved or there is more than one version of your project in play. How are you running this? I don't use streamlit... is it running on a different machine or in a different pythen venv than your code?

Comment: To be clear, the code doesn't think `Controllers.ClienteController` has an attribute `Incluir`. But your code shows that it does. Meaning... you aren't running the code you think you are. You'll have to work on why.

Comment: I think streamlit uses local machine, its first time im using it too. The command line to start : 

streamlit run main.py

Comment: Yes, the problem is exactly that. Maybe im running streamlit wrong ? Because not make any sense to me the error, as Controllers.ClienteController has an attribute Incluir

Comment: @tdelaney appreciate the help bro. Ty, im trying some print()

Comment: `os.path.abspath(ClienteController.__file__)` would be interesting. And if you are using jupyter or something, it may be a question of hitting "save".

Answer (score 1):

A great help in debugging such type of problems is to check with:

```
print([e for e in dir(object) if e[0]!='_'])
```

which methods the object actually has. So you can see for example where you have a typo. Another advantage of this is that you check this way if what you think you have is actually there instead of assuming there is a problem with the software or the computer. The error message states clearly there is no `Incluir` in the imported module ... So the question is why don't you trust what the error message tells you? Because you think it can't be and there must be an issue with the system?

You can see in the comments:

> To be clear, the code doesn't think Controllers.ClienteController has
> an attribute Incluir. But your code shows that it does. Meaning... you
> aren't running the code you think you are. You'll have to work on why.
> –  tdelaney

Just inject some print() and dir() statements into your code in order to see where your assumptions about what is going on are wrong.

*And ... MAKE SURE you actually **saved** the code you have posted so the right code is imported. Not that you look at the right code, but in the file there is another one, with a typo.*

As you see in the comments:

```
os.path.abspath(ClienteController.__file__)
```

would be interesting. And

> if you are using jupyter or something, it may be a question of hitting
> "save". –  tdelaney

I am not alone with my suggestions.

At the end you will probably post the answer to your question yourself ... we are here only to help you in helping yourself with the ideas. The idea with `__file__` is sure an interesting one and may reveal that you are importing another file from another directory as that one you think you are importing.

Comment: Just see with the dir(object) above and a print() in def Incluir() if what you assume it is, is actually true.

Comment: Looking at my code i think that Incluir from ClienteController is not found. But idknow why 

Because in my main i have the line :
import Controllers.ClienteController as ClienteController

Comment: The Error raised shows clearly that there is no `Incluir` defined in imported `ClienteController` ... now find out how it comes that it is not there and which of what you assuming is wrong.

Comment: @tdelaney you were right with the function vs. attribute call ... I have updated my answer ... the error message comes at the level of variable name resolution. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone who helped me here.Really appreciate that help

I dont know why, but after a lot of search and print(), i found that the error was in the connection with SQL, that's why the code cant reached ControllersCliente even if the error not saying about that.

The solution for me :
pip unistall all the sql-connectors and install again